# Developing fast twitch muscle fibers in kids?

Tags: basketball, running, training

What are suggestions for starting training for fast twitch development with kids of young ages?

I am a big sports fan and I've had my experiences as professional athlete, right now I am training a group of kids between 10-12 years and am I am planning to start training them more speed drills and implement plyometrics soft drills. As I've seen in the past that guys with more speed had more success in any other sports! So I am looking for some cons and pros arguments about this topic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowing how much vertical jumping is important in basketball, some **safe** plyometric workouts for 10-12 y/o kids would be to have them squat down and jump up as high as possible while reaching up with one or both hands and hit a flag or a point directly above them. Then, upon landing, immediately jump up again and attempt to reach higher. It is important to use both upper and lower body movement, to keep landings short, and to perform multiple jumps in succession.

Another exercise to work on quick muscle twitching, and foot speed would be to have them run various ladder drills. Some good drills include:

- The Two Step High Knee Drill - Simply step both feet into each space of the ladder, one at a time, as you forward.
- The High Knee Drill - This drill is very similar to the Two Step High Knee Drill, but you’ll only be landing one foot in each space on the ladder.
- The Right Legged Thrust Drill - only the right leg will be inside the ladder while the left leg will stay on the outside for balance and support
- The Left Legged Thrust  Drill - Opposite of the The Right Legged Thrust Drill
- The Double Foot Shuffle Drill - Begin on the left side of the ladder, directly beside the first space. Then step each foot into the first space one at a time (right foot first, then left foot). Continuing right, immediately step each foot outside of the ladder one at a time, (again, right foot first, then left foot). As you step outside the ladder, plant with the outside foot (the right foot) and then step into the ladder’s second space (this time, left foot in first, followed by the right foot).
- The Single Foot Shuffle Drill - Begin the same way as the Double Foot Shuffle. Step into the ladder with each foot, one at a time (right foot, then left foot). Then step out on the other side with just the outside (right) foot. Then, step into the second space with your left foot, step with the right, step outside the ladder with your left foot, and then step into the third space with your right foot.

These are some very basic exercises for developing fast twitch muscles, which are easy and safe for the ages previously mentioned. Hope these descriptions make sense.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I was just sitting her and thinking, but if one thinks about it, just about all professional sports players have incredible hip-flexor flexibility. Doing stretches that focus around the hip-flexor would be another great way to develop overall fast twitch muscles.